# Modify member variable of object held in QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I have a QVariantList containing objects of different classes.  I need to modify a member variable of one object held in the list.  My code runs, but the object is not changing (looks like a copy of the object is being changed).  Here is sample code similar to what I'm doing:

```
QVariantList l;
QVariant v = l.at(0);
MyClass c;
if (v.canConvert<MyClass >()) c = v.value<MyClass >();
c.myfield(10);
// l.at(0) has not changed
```

I also tried:

```
qvariant_cast<MyClass>(v).myfield(10)
```

but no difference.  I want to change myfield of the object, not a copy of the object. How do I modify the 'myfield' field of the object held in the QVariant v.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is copied here the first time:

```
QVariant v = l.at(0);
```

`v` contains a new object. All your manipulations change this copy not the object in the list.
Change it to this:

```
QVariant& v = l.at(0);
```

Now you have a reference to the right QVariant stored in the list.

`qvariant_cast` also creates a copy:

```
T qvariant_cast ( const QVariant & value )
```

And `v.value<MyClass >()` too:

```
T QVariant::value () const
```

That's why you need to convert `v` to `MyClass`, change it and assign it back to `v`. Here is one of possible solutions:

```
QVariantList l;
QVariant v& = l.at(0);   
if (v.canConvert<MyClass >())
{
   MyClass c = v.value<MyClass>();
   c.myfield(10);
   v = QVariant::fromValue(c);
}
```

Instead of using the reference you also you could still use `QVariant v = l.at(0);` but at the end call `l[0] = QVariant::fromValue(c)`.

Comment: You need to use the operator[](int i) instead of QVariantList::at(int i) cause it's const and returns a const reference

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
c.myfield(10);
v = c;
```

See the following example as specified in QVariant docs.

```
 QDataStream in(...);            // (opening the previously written stream)
 in >> v;                        // Reads an Int variant
 int z = v.toInt();              // z = 123
 qDebug("Type is %s",            // prints "Type is int"
         v.typeName());
 v = v.toInt() + 100;            // The variant now hold the value 223
 v = QVariant(QStringList());
```

You can refer to the [QVariant docs here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html)

Answer (score 0):

`QVariant::data()` is your friend. It wasn't officially documented [before Qt6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#data), but you can safely use it nevertheless with Qt5 too.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass
{
public:
    int myfield {0};
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>();

    QVariantList l;
    {
        QVariant t;
        MyClass mc;
        t.setValue(mc);

        l.append(t);
        l.append(t);
        l.append(t);
    }

    // ...

    {
        QVariant &v (l[0]); // obviously we don't use "at" since it's const and we need to modify the container

        if(v.userType() != qMetaTypeId<MyClass>())
        {
            qWarning() << "Unexpected metatype " << QMetaType::typeName(v.userType());
            return -1;
        }

        MyClass *const ptr {static_cast<MyClass*>(v.data())};
        ptr->myfield = 10;
    }

    // ...

    qDebug() << l.at(0).value<MyClass>().myfield; // returns 10

    return 0;
}
```